# Fetching Apollo Server on Heroku return "forward is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, heroku, graphql, apollo

I have deployed the apollo-server on Heroku.
Url https://rocky-sands-20819.herokuapp.com/

A testing query

```
query Users {
    allUsers {
      name
    }
  }
```

You can see you succesfully get response.

But when I try use it in react app, the query will return an error.

Here is the restlink

```
const restLink = new RestLink({
  uri: "https://rocky-sands-20819.herokuapp.com/",
});

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: restLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

When I use `const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_USERS)` The error will return an error saying `Error: Network error: forward is not a function` - I am using the same query as in playground

This react-app works, when I test with `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/`

What goes wrong?

SOLUTION:

Works after I replaced

```
const restLink = new RestLink({
  uri: "https://rocky-sands-20819.herokuapp.com/",
});
```

with

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: "https://rocky-sands-20819.herokuapp.com/graphql"
});
```

Comment: You should share a repo or sandbox link with a minimal reproduction of the issue. At the very least, you should include the versions of the relevant libraries and how you're importing everything when creating your ApolloClient instance. At a glance, it sounds like `apollo-link-rest` is probably not compatible with whatever version of apollo client you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you sending GraphQL queries to a REST endpoint (that's what I assume from RestLink usage) you may need to change slightly your queries.

You may find the examples here; https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/rest/#quick-start

@rest directive is used within the queries to specify the end point. Like following;

```
const query = gql`
  query luke {
   person @rest(type: "Person", path: "people/1/") {
   name
  }
 }`;
```

I don't know how your backend is designed and I have never used GraphQL with REST backend but I hope it is helpful.

If your backend is not a REST service may be you should not use RestLink and simply specify the URI within the ApolloClient constructor.

Comment: Hi, you can see the endpoint I use in restlink. You can also see it works with that query on the heroku link. Så I don't think it has something to do with the query itself. But thanks for your thoughts

Comment: Why do you use RestLink then? Why don't you simply set the uri within the ApolloClient constructor? I am asking because I don't know what brings extra the RestLink.

Comment: Sorry, can you give me and example?

Comment: See here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/get-started/#create-a-client

Comment: I works now, after replace RestLink with const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: "https://rocky-sands-20819.herokuapp.com/"
});